# How to convert list to string in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, converters

I have a list. I want to convert it to string. However, the results are a bit different from what I expected.

Expected result:

```
'["a", "b", "c", "d"]'
```

Actual result:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

My code:

```
final List list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

print(list.toString());
```

How can I get my expected results? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @eamirho3ein I don't understand why you said "looks like regular word"

Comment: @eamirho3ein are you saying that when I use print('"a"'); it returns the result a?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes you are right

Comment: @eamirho3ein can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337814/13997210) question and [its](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337973/13997210) answer, in this answer I want to change the color of children text when I click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `jsonEncode` of it to get the desired result:

```
print(jsonEncode(list));
```

Comment: this would convert the list to string.

Comment: @eamirho3ein of course... read the title of the question

Comment: Hi @Ivo, this solved my problem! I can't accept it now, I'll accept it in 6 minutes

Comment: I assumed his question was about the way string prints. now make sense.

Comment: @Ivo I accepted your answer :)

Comment: @Ivo can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337814/13997210) question and [its](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337973/13997210) answer, in this answer I want to change the color of children text when I click

Answer (score 0):

You can try `jsonEncode`:

```
final List list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

print(jsonEncode(list));
```

Output:

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by using `json.encode()` function:

```
final list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
final result = json.encode(list);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).